# store function arguments inside the function and apply them for future use in r

Tags: r, function

I have fairly complex function but the following is simplified version of what I would like to do.

Let's suppose I have the following function set to return list where I want to store arguments passed to the function as one of element.

```
myfun <- function (a, x, y, z, ...){
         out <- a+x+y+z
         arg <- list(x=x,y=y, z=z,...)
         outlist <- list(out=out, arg=arg)
         return(outlist)
         }
```

Here I am storing argument within the function as list. The purpose of storing arguments is that I can apply them exactly same within other function without writing them again. Just using the returned output data object we can run the function reproducible manner.

Let's say I want only vary `a` but other will be same in other application of the function.

```
xy <- myfun(a=4,x=5,y=6,z=9,k=10)
myfun(a=10, xy$arg)
Error in a + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
myfun(a=6, xy$arg)
```

How can I do this ?

Edits:

**Some clarifications:**

`myfun` arguments are dynamic - means that can take different arguments - for example K in the above example. It can be next time:

```
xy <- myfun(a=4,x=5,y=6,z=9,k=10, l=13)
```

My idea was to store all arguments passed in one run as list (`arg$outlist`) and list can have different elements at different times.

Comment: I recommend to read `?match.call` and `?substitute` and all the subsequent linked docs regarding quoted expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach may suit your needs as well:

```
hijack <- function (FUN, ...) {
    .FUN <- FUN
    args <- list(...)
    invisible(lapply(seq_along(args), function(i) {
        formals(.FUN)[[names(args)[i]]] <<- args[[i]]
    }))
    .FUN
}


myfun <- function (a, x, y, z, ...) sum(..., a, x, y, z)

myfun2 <- hijack(myfun, a=4,x=5,y=6,z=9)

myfun2(4)
myfun2(10)

## > myfun2(4)
## [1] 24
## > myfun2(10)
## [1] 30
## > myfun2(6)
## [1] 26
```

Answer (score 7):

You want to **[Curry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)** your function:

```
> myfun <- function (a, x, y, z, ...) a+x+y+z
> library(functional)
> myfun2 <- Curry(myfun, x=5,y=6,z=9,k=10)
> myfun2(4)
[1] 24         # == 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 4
> myfun2(10)
[1] 30         # == 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 10
> myfun2(6)
[1] 26         # == 5 + 6 + 9 + 10 + 6
```

`Curry` creates a new function with all the specified arguments pre-set.  You can then just use that new function.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is there anyway to make the myfun2 dynamic - what I mean by this is that myfun is dynamic function and can have any number of arguments - at different times. Just I did within my function arg can capture all the arguments. Is there way to pass it while using Curry function ?